# Sed is not replacing all occurrences of pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I've got a the following variable `LINES` with the format `date;album;song;duration;singer;author;genre`.

```
August 2013;MDNA;Falling Free;00:31:40;Madonna;Madonna;Pop
August 2013;MDNA;I don't give a;00:45:40;Madonna;Madonna;Pop
August 2013;MDNA;I'm a sinner;01:00:29;Madonna;Madonna;Pop
August 2013;MDNA;Give Me All Your Luvin';01:15:02;Madonna;Madonna;Pop
```

I want to output `author-song`, so I made this script:

```
echo $LINES | sed s_"^[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]*\);[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]*\)"_"\2-\1"_g
```

The desired output is:

```
Madonna-Falling Free
Madonna-I don't give a
Madonna-I'm a sinner
Madonna-Give Me All Your Luvin'
```

However, I am getting this:

```
Madonna-Falling Free;Madonna;Pop August 2013;MDNA;I don't give a;00:45:40;Madonna;Madonna;Pop August 2013;MDNA;I'm a sinner;01:00:29;Madonna;Madonna;Pop August 2013;MDNA;Give Me All Your Luvin';01:15:02;Madonna;Madonna;Pop
```

Why?

EDIT: I need to use sed.

Comment: Why do you need to use `sed`? Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `sed` to see more than one line of input, you must quote the variable to echo:

```
echo "$LINES" | sed ...
```

Note that I'm not even going to try to evaluate the correctness of your `sed` script; using `sed` here is a travesty, given that `awk` is so much better suited to the task.

Answer (score 3):

When I run your `sed` script on your input, I get this output:

```
Madonna-Falling Free;Pop
Madonna-I don't give a;Pop
Madonna-I'm a sinner;Pop
Madonna-Give Me All Your Luvin';Pop
```

which is fine except for the extra `;Pop` - you just need to add `.*$` to the end of your regex so that the entire line is replaced.

Based on your reported output, I'm guessing your input file is using a different newline convention from what `sed` expects.

In any case, this is a pretty silly thing to use `sed` for.  Much better with `awk`, for instance:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";";OFS="-"} {print $5,$3}'
```

or, slightly more tersely,

```
awk -F\; -vOFS=- '{print $5,$3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sed is viewing your entire sample text as a single line. So it is performing the operation requested and then leaving the rest unchanged.
I would look into the newline issue first. How are you populating $LINES?
You should also add to the pattern that seventh field in your input (genre), so that the expression actually does consume all of the text that you want it to. And perhaps anchor the end of the pattern on `$` or `\b` (word boundary) or `\s` (a spacey character) or `\n` (newline).

Answer (score 0):

If your format is absolutely permanent, just try below:

```
echo $line | sed 's#.*;.*;\(.*\);.*;.*;\(.*\);.*#\2-\1#'
```

Comment: Also you can use cut and awk:         echo $line | cut -f 6,3 -d ";" | sed "s/;/\-/g"  or  echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $6-$3}' | sed "s/;/\-/g"